# YouTube is stuttering in chrome on a brand new computer

Tags: google-chrome, ssd, windows-8.1, youtube, lag

So I just hooked up a brand new rig with an Asus P9X79 WS board, an i7-4820k chip, 16GB of G.Skill TridentX RAM, Evga GTX 650(soon to be upgraded in the future), and I’ve got one 1TB HDD with 500GB SSD Samsung EVO 840 as the main drive. I installed Windows 8.1 and all of the driver CDs that came with the rig.

Yet when I’ve got Chrome up an running, there is some notable stuttering in various YouTube videos. It usually occurs on its own or when I’m opening, scrolling through links, or even refreshing in any tabs. It is also much more frequent on HD videos. I have already checked the `chrome://plugins`. The PepperFlash is unchecked and I should be running the Macromedia version. So I’m stumped.

I mean come on, a rig like this shouldn’t have this much trouble playing a YouTube video. Especially when my Lenovo Y410P with Windows 8.1 can play videos flawlessly on chrome.

What baffles me further is this error is non-existent in Internet Explorer. Plays the videos without so much as a complaint unlike Chrome here. I might try some more browsers in the meantime(as IE lacks a youtube re-player extension), but it leaves me distraught that Chrome is having this issue.

Comment: check about:gpu and post results

Comment: Related http://www.tomsguide.com/answers/id-1978782/flash-videos-youtube-play-stuttering.html

Answer (score 1):

Well I've done some more research on the issue. What I've found the common similarities of the issue with users having Dual Monitor Displays(which I forgot to mention) , using an SSD for the OS, and an a secondary HDD. I've managed to eliminate the lag by forcing Chrome to install on my HDD instead. But I am unfortunately unable to load HD videos now at all for whatever reason. Its not clean work around, but I suppose its what I'll have to live with for now.

What ever the issue is seems to be a problem with the SSD, As my GTX 650 had no issues playing HD videos on dual screens on my HDD within my older rig.

Comment: I have dual monitors and am using an SSD for OS and have no problems generally with Youtube

Answer (score 1):

I have recently experienced a similar issue. I just blocked access to adobe flash for youtube.com. Youtube responded by playing the videos in HTML5. After that, the lag just disappeared.

Answer (score 0):

I have a series of questions, as it could be because of a lot of reasons.

1. Do you have the latest drivers, especially your video driver and chipset driver?
2. Have you tried clearing your cache and cookies?
3. Does this happen in Firefox (i know you said it does not happen in IE)
4. Is this a clean install of windows? I assume it is.
5. Do you have the required add-ons, such as flash, java, shockwave, etc?

I will just say that I have had the same problem as you, and I tried reinstalling windows, checked my drivers, made sure my cache and cookies were cleared, etc and when I replaced my hard drive it fixed the problem. My hard drive was about 3 or 4 years old and I guess it had slowed down.

Driver discs are almost always outdated. I would recommend downloading the latest drivers from the official website.

Comment: 1) From what I can see I believe all my drivers are up to date. 2) I have done so, alas no change as of yet. 3) Just installed firefox, I'm getting slight visual frame lag from the video but no audio lag like chrome. 4) I believe it is. I installed it straight away after assembling the parts. 5) My Flash player claims to be up to date.

Comment: @s0ra  the answer  to #1 wasn't very clear.  Did you download the latest det drivers from Nvidia? or did you use what was on the disk that came with it?   (Rule #1 of video-cards.  NEVER USE THE DRIVERS ON THE DISK  They are guaranteed to be old... and probably buggy)

Comment: I did install Geforce Experience and am currently running the 332.21 WHQL drivers.

Comment: As I said my problm was my hard drive, I think maybe your SSD is defective, you should try doing a speedtest on it.